# Issues getting right response from remote php file with JQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

his form is working with the required and email check, however, when I do remote, it is giving really weird responses.
I'm not totally sure I'm returning the right thing from my php. When I set it to return the variables, it will just put up the first checked value and say it already exists, even though it doesn't, and leave it there even when I change the input..  I tried echoing the value in the php, though so I know it's getting the right values.  And If I echo out the $valid variable instead of returning it, the message gets set to '1' and stays like that whether there's a match or not.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, it seems to be fairly straightforward, but it may be that I'm not understanding what's supposed to be passed through the JSON. Let me know what you think, I've run out of things to try!

```
 $(function() { 
    $("#registrationForm").validate({ 
        rules: { 
            email: {  
                required: true, 
                email: true, 
                remote: "checkEmail.php" 
            }
        }
 messages: { 
             email: { 
                 required: "This field is required", 
                 email: "Please enter a valid email address", 
                 remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use") 
             }
         }
    }); 
 });
```

The php:

```
$check = trim(strtolower($_GET['email']));
$valid = true;
foreach ($model->getAllUsers() as $users) {
   if ($users->email == $check) {
       $valid = false;
   } 
}
return $valid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `echo json_encode($valid);` as the output. It mentioned JSON encode in the documentation, but I guess it threw me off that the example php they had did not use it.